# Animate many faces

Tags: animation, shape-keys

I have about 40 faces I want to animate one after another, kind of like 40 pillars in a row, scaling one up after another.

I made an example where I do it with 3 faces and a *Shape Key* animation for each of the three faces.

Is there any better way to do this? Or do I have to do 40 Shape keys for each single pillar I want to animate?

[image: screenshot of the pillars]

[Sample .blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xD6SrjtySIFgMKNfhbNXyuFrxN5gACWp/view?usp=drive_link) which should clarify what I want to achieve.

Comment: since we have no idea how the animation looks like, i would at least recommend providing a short animation video - or better: provide blend file. Just by text we have no idea how the animation looks like.

Comment: @Chris ... what more do you need to know about anim? OP described animation - "pillar row scaling one up after another! ... anything that is not clear from description?

Comment: @Chris : I added a link to a sample .blend file

Comment: @vklidu I wasn't sure what the animation should look like either. There were many questions: along which axis should the 40 "faces" be scaled (all axes or just one)? To what extent and over what period? When will it be stopped? How strong is the scaling? (linear, exponential?) Which pivot point should be used for scaling, from the center or the ground? - The screenshot and the blend file now answer these questions :-) By the way, here you can also see that the pillars are not arranged in a row but in a circle ;-) If you want a GN solution these little details are important.

Comment: @RobertNagel Hello. Thanks for the blend file. Please include also at least a screenshot next time. The blend file is great but if the file is no longer available, the question is again completely unclear.

Comment: @Blunder thank you very much. Will Do in future posts. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I guess you can raise the faces one by one with Geometry Nodes and a help object (to define the chosen faces).